# SQL error when trying to copy value from column based on condition

Tags: sql-server

```
with dummytable as
(
    Select table2.number, table2.paymentto
    from table2
    inner join table1 on table1.number = table2.number and table2.number='1'
    and table2.paymentto is not null and table2.paymentto !='B'
)

update table1
set ProvCOBAdjustments = (Select TotCOBAdjustmentAmt
    from table1, dummytable
    where dummytable.paymentto='P'and dummytable.number = table1.number)
where table1.paymentto is null;
```

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "update"

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's what is causing the error, but your final `where` clause looks wrong:

```
where table.paymentto is null
```

Shouldn't it read:

```
where table1.paymentto is null
```

instead?

Comment: Sorry, that was just a typo...i replaced my actual table name with table1 and table2...

Comment: i'm running this query with actual table names in my machine, and i'm getting syntax error

Comment: @Ramya - your table names don't have spaces/odd characters/use reserved keywords, do they? I can't see how you're getting a *syntax error* with this query.

Answer (score 0):

There is no syntax error in this code. There might be something with your original table names or something in the code before or after what you have posted here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
update table1
set ProvCOBAdjustments = TotCOBAdjustmentAmt 
    from table1, dummytable
    where dummytable.paymentto='P'and dummytable.number = table1.number
and table1.paymentto is null;
```

Otherwise you're trying to do some kind of correlated subquery, and it all goes quite pearshaped.

---

Also, comma style joining tends to be frowned upon these days - I'd re-write the join as:

```
update t1
set
   ProvCOBAdjustments = TotCOBAdjustmentAmt 
from
   table1 t1
      inner join
   dummytable dt
      on
         dt.number = t1.number
where
    dt.paymentto='P' and
    t1.paymentto is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the version of SQL Server?

If it is SQL Server 2000 or earlier, then you cannot run this query in its present form.

This query uses the so called CTE, Common Table Expression (the `with dummytable as (...)` part). CTE support was introduced in SQL Server 2005.

SQL Server 2008 R2, installed on my somputer, does not complain about syntax in this query.